# How to put JSP in WEB-INF correct?

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, web-inf

I'm using MVC and want to put my JSP pages in WEB-INF to avoid direct access to it. I have an index.jsp page and other pages in jsp folder in Web Content and it works. It looks like this:

```
-Web Content
-index.jsp
-jsp
--main_read.jsp
--...
```

By the way, index.jsp is my login page and whether user is logged, in controller I use

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("jsp/main_read.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

I works perfect, but when I'm trying to put my JSP in WEB-INF it fails:

```
-Web Content
-index.jsp
-WEB-INF
--jsp
---jsp
----main_read.jsp
----...
```

And gives an error like this

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Libruary/jsp/main_read.jsp

type Status report

message /Libruary/jsp/main_read.jsp

description The requested resource (/Libruary/jsp/main_read.jsp) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
```

Probably the problem is in the page path, I write in `dispatcher.forward`, but anyway, help me please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to pass the path `/jsp/main_read.jsp`, and the JSP is in `/WEB-INF/jsp/jsp/main_read.jsp`. Obviously, the paths don't match. Pass the correct path to `getRequestDispatcher()`: `/WEB-INF/jsp/jsp/main_read.jsp`.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> The pathname must begin with a / and is interpreted as relative to the
>   current context root